# using livewire 3 and laravel 10.10 [simple input data binding is not working]

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, laravel-10, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

I am working in:

> Livewire 3, Laravel version is `10.10`, PHP `8.2.4`

I am trying to bind simple data with simple code but its not working, I am not sure why? Can you please help me? Livewire actions functions on click working, but data binding not updating data while typing in input field.

**user.blade.php**

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" wire:model="name" id="description">
    Hi! My name is {{ $name }}
    <script>
        console.log("Livewire JavaScript loaded and working!");
    </script>
</div>
```

**User.Php**

```php
namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class User extends Component
{

    public $name = 'ali';


    public function render()
    {

        return view('livewire.user');
    }
}
```

On page load Output shows "ali" in the input field, but when I type more characters in input fields its not updating variable value.

Comment: sorry, i did not understand what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation you can read :
By default, Livewire only sends a network request when the form is submitted (or any other action is called), not while the form is being filled out.

change your input code as below :

`<input type="text" wire:model.live="name" id="description">`

Comment: i have one more question i am learning $queryString  for search. now when filling in the search bar its updating link live but the record not updating live, but when i refresh page then record updates according to the search query, its means my query is correct the problem is why its not update without reloading page..    <div>

    <input type="search" wire:model.live="search">
    <table>
@foreach($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$user->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->email}}</td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach

    </table>

</div>

Comment: public $search;
    protected $queryString = ['search'];

    public function render()
    {
        $users = \App\Models\User::query()
            ->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
            ->get();

        return view('livewire.user', ['users' => $users]);
    }

Comment: oops, this was due to <table> in table record not updating when I tried <ul> it updating live records thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Did you include your livewire script or load unless include it by

```
@livewireScripts
```

add it to your main/master blade file. Also, try clearing all cache by

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If you need to ask for clarification, or make a suggestion, please do it as a comment.

Comment: Hi, @livewireScripts automatically loading in livewire 3 from layouts/app.blade.php I have checked the script from "view source page" livewireScripts successfully loading by default. <!-- Livewire Scripts -->
<script src="/livewire/livewire.js?id=3605227a"  data-csrf="t3Q88cd9E2tJlLbADrNWyckCJuBsL91kr3UGK7d5" data-uri="/livewire/update" data-navigate-once="true"></script>
<script> also, I have tried php artisan optimize:clear but my issue is same

Comment: i think the ajax request are not working properly,